# Why does `Hint Resolve X` fail, where `lets : X` works?

Tags: coq

Here's a logic puzzle about self-referential sentences that I'm trying to automate in Coq. The goal is to prove `P1`. I'm also using the LibTactics library from Software Foundations.

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import LibTactics. 

Inductive symbol : Type := | P | Q | P' | Q'.

Definition sentence : Type := list symbol.

Variable true : sentence -> Prop.

Variable provable : sentence -> Prop.

Hypothesis HQ'1 : forall (X : sentence), true (Q' :: X) -> ~ provable (X ++ X).
Hint Resolve HQ'1.

Hypothesis HQ'2 : forall (X : sentence), ~ provable (X ++ X) -> true (Q' :: X).
Hint Resolve HQ'2.

Hypothesis HC : forall (X : sentence), provable X -> true X.
Hint Resolve HC.

Theorem P1 : 
true [Q';Q'] /\ ~ provable [Q';Q'].
```

The following solution works, but seems unnecessarily long :

```
Theorem P1 : 
true [Q';Q'] /\ ~ provable [Q';Q'].
lets : HQ'1. lets : HQ'2. lets : HC.  
jauto. Qed.
```

From what I understand, adding `X` to the context by `lets : X` is just one way of making lemma `X` available to auto. Since I already added `HQ'1`, `HQ'2`, and `HC` to hint database with `Hint Resolve`, all the `lets` in the solution above are redundant, and the following should also work :

```
Theorem P1 : 
true [Q';Q'] /\ ~ provable [Q';Q'].
jauto. Qed.
```

But it does not. What's the difference between the two? Does Coq treat hypotheses in context and hint database differently?